# Uable to attach database in sql express

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

I am not able to attach the databases in sql express edition with service pack 4.it is showing error .It was working fine till few hours back.

I am logged in as windows authentication.My os is windows 7.

i have attached the screen shoot of error[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Operating system permission on that .mdf file to full permission. In short, change the permission to 'Everyone'. It will not give that error

Answer (score 2):

User you are logged in when you are trying to attach the database does not have permission to access the file in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server...".

Try to login as "sa" or use Windows Authentication with user that has permission to access file you are trying to attach.